# Boolean functions as a composition of negation and conjunction/disjunction

Tags: logic

I have read that any boolean function can be written as a composition of negation, conjunction and disjunction. And since disjunction can be written only in terms of negation and conjunction, it follows that you would only need negation and conjunction (or negation and disjunction). My question is: What is this theorem called? Who proved it? How do you prove it? I can't find anything on the matter, other than "it is widely known...", etc..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because because it belongs to the [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange site.

Comment: Search for "Adequare set of connectives"

Comment: It has been "discovered" end of 19th century: Peirce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functional completeness is the concept you're describing here as referenced [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness):

> In logic, a functionally complete set of logical connectives or Boolean operators is one which can be used to express all possible truth tables by combining members of the set into a Boolean expression. A well-known complete set of connectives is { AND, NOT }, consisting of binary conjunction and negation. Each of the singleton sets { NAND } and { NOR } is functionally complete.

It is widely known that Emil Post first rigorously proved that there are (up
to term equivalence) only five maximally functional incomplete logical signatures, which you can see from the same reference above:

> Emil Post proved that a set of logical connectives is functionally complete if and only if it is not a subset of any of the following 5 sets of connectives: 1) The monotonic connectives; 2) The affine connectives; 3) The self-dual connectives; 4) The truth-preserving connectives; 5) The falsity-preserving connectives;

As for the basic insight of the proof in your concerned case, it's based on a well-known theorem that any propositional logic formula can be converted into an equivalent disjunctive normal form (DNF) with literals only (atoms or negation of atoms), same goes for conjunctive normal form (CNF). A more advanced model-theoretic insight is that functional completeness derives from the fact that for a finite field, each operation on its domain is representable by a *suitable* polynomial.